# resize images and keep them with new size in new folder in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, resize-image

I write the following code in matlab. from this code I take sequence of images as input from a folder and resize these images. Now I need to store them with new size on output folder.  any one help me to update this code.

```
fileFolder = fullfile('D:','Texture DataBases','images3000');
dirOutput = dir(fullfile(fileFolder,'image*.jpg'));
fileNames = {dirOutput.name};

for k=1:length(fileNames)
                   H=fileNames{k};
              S=imread(H); 
              I-resize(S, [300 300]);
imshow(I);
end

......
......
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant:

```
I=imresize(S, [300 300]);
```

You can save images with [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html):

```
imwrite(I,fullfile('D:','New_folder',H);
```

Additionally, you can use [`mkdir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mkdir.html) to create the new output folder (`New_folder` in the example above).